# How can I have Ruby on Rails output Bootstrap v3 scaffolding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, scaffolding

I'd like to be able to use `Bootstrap 3` and `Sass` in my `RoR` project and have the scaffolding generator output `Bootstrap 3` HTML. I'm using Ruby 2 with Rails 4.

Nothing too fancy - mostly just having the forms buttons have the appropriate CSS classes.

I've used the [Rails Tutorial Sample App (ver 4)](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4) as a base which includes the `bootstrap-sass` gem - but when I use the generator the HTML does not have the proper bootstrap classes - for instance the buttons don't have the `btn btn-default` class.

I realize that the scaffolding is behaving as it was designed to, it is a base and is meant to be customized (or replaced) - but it seems like it should not be hard to also have the generated HTML be "Bootstrap Ready"

[image]

A related question had an answer where someone mentioned that editing the files in the directory `lib/erb/scaffold` like `edit.html.erb` - would override the default templates that Rails uses for scaffolding. I'm not opposed to that but I was hoping that there might be a something like a `gem` that already did this.

I like using the `bootstrap-sass` gem and I hope that there is a solution that would be compatible with it - I'd rather use `scss` than `less`

Seems like there should be several gems to do this.

Comment: So the problem is what, exactly?  That your templates don't have the classes applied to them that you want?

Comment: yes - I want the generated template to have the default bootstrap classes for the elements that they contain ( buttons, tables, forms, etc )

Comment: if u are using simple_form, u can customize it to add default elements. like config.button_class = 'btn btn-primary'. Also, there is no official release of simple form supporting BS3

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've had the same trouble but finally found this:
https://github.com/decioferreira/bootstrap-generators

It includes Bootstrap 3.1 and provides scaffolding and you can choose haml and scss as well as other options.

For example when I did `rails g scaffold Link guid:string profile:string media_url:string`

It automatically produced this:

[image: automatically scaffolded with Bootstrap 3]

EDIT FOR HEROKU USERS

I did have trouble pushing my app that is using bootstrap-generators (v3.1.1) to Heroku. Heroku was giving the error `File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.scss`

The fix turned out to be to modify the automatically generated bootstrap-generators.scss file. Change `@import "bootstrap.scss";` to `@import "bootstrap";` (eg just remove the extension).

NEW EDIT FOR HEROKU USERS
The new gem 3.1.1.1 fixes the bug. You no longer need to change `@import "bootstrap.scss";` to `@import "bootstrap";` in the bootstrap-geneerators.scss file.

Comment: very nice. i also found [bootstrap-sass-extras](https://github.com/doabit/bootstrap-sass-extras) recently but I think yours looks better.

Comment: i tried that one too, but this one seems to be a more general solution

Comment: Strange, that this answer (and question) was not upvoted more.

Comment: I have followed your advice and used bootstrap-generators successfully. Even after adding the  [Bootswatch CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/#bootswatch_tab) things were smooth. However I noticed that if I create a scaffold the resulting form uses the standard fields and buttons and not the bootstrap ones. Do you know how can i fix this so those form are automatically generated with the bootstrap formatting?

Answer (score 5):

If you need to customize your generated views more you can actually override the default views with your own.

Just put them in `lib/templates/{erb|haml}/scaffold`. You can see some example files [here](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/master/lib/generators/bootstrap/themed/templates).

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics

Comment: Here is the link to the actual gem https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Comment: that won't help you, you said you want bootstrap 3 and afaik twitter-boostrap-rails is still on Bootstrap v2.X